# cron - one script works while the other doesn't

Tags: bash, cron, archlinux, systemd

I am on Archlinux and I am trying to force a cron application to execute my script. So I installed package fcron and ran it's daemon first and then I added fcrontab which looks like this:

```
* * * * * /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript
```

Ok so this is where it gets tricky. This script will execute if it's contents looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin
touch ~/test-002.txt
```

But it won't execute if it's contents look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin
acpi -b | awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | {
    read -r status capacity
    if [ "$status" = Discharging -a "$capacity" -lt 5 ]; then
        logger "Critical battery threshold"
        systemctl hibernate
    fi
}
```

Why is that? Even the [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/laptop#hibernate_on_low_battery_level) says it should work, but I assume it is wrong - I only changed `#!/bin/bash` and added `PATH=/usr/bin`. **Script works on its own...**

---

**EDIT:**

So I edited my script to look like below and it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
SHELL=/bin/sh

/usr/bin/acpi -b | /usr/bin/awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | (
    read -r status capacity
    if [ "$status" = Discharging ] && [ "$capacity" -lt 50 ]; then
        /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
    fi
)
```

If I run

```
[ziga@ziga-laptop hibernate]$ run-parts ~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/ -v
run-parts: executing /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate//hibernatescript
```

My PC hibernates, but again cron doesn't hibernate my PC using the exact same script. I also tried fcron and it doesn't work although daemon is fully running and fcrontab is set. Again this works for any simpler scripts while it wont work for this one.

Here are some info:

```
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ systemctl status fcron.service     
● fcron.service - fcron periodical command scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fcron.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-06-21 10:39:48 CEST; 58min ago
  Process: 419 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fcron (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 423 (fcron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/fcron.service
           └─423 /usr/bin/fcron

Jun 21 11:34:00 ziga-laptop fcron[12833]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:34:02 ziga-laptop fcron[12833]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:35:00 ziga-laptop fcron[13021]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:35:02 ziga-laptop fcron[13021]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:36:00 ziga-laptop fcron[13210]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:36:02 ziga-laptop fcron[13210]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:37:00 ziga-laptop fcron[13407]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:37:02 ziga-laptop fcron[13407]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:38:00 ziga-laptop fcron[13599]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
Jun 21 11:38:02 ziga-laptop fcron[13599]: Job '/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescrip
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ fcrontab -l
2016-06-21 11:38:48  INFO listing ziga's fcrontab
* * * * * /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ cat /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript
#!/bin/sh
SHELL=/bin/sh

/usr/bin/acpi -b | /usr/bin/awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | (
        read -r status capacity
        if [ "$status" = Discharging ] && [ "$capacity" -lt 50 ]; then
                /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
        fi
)
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ ls -l /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ziga users  214 Jun 21 08:46 hibernatescript
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ziga users 2832 Jun 21 00:24 README.txt
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ groups ziga
lp audio bumblebee users
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$
```

Comment: Add full path to `acpi`, `awk`, `logger`, `systemctl` or expand `$PATH` variable with paths.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I already executed `echo $PATH` in terminal emulator and copied the output in my script and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Cyrus I changed both pairs of `{}` with `()` and it doesn't work. Which pair did you mean?

Comment: @Cyrus I also tried fixing my script using shellcheck... Doesn't help...

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Please read the topic - script runs without any problems on it's own...

Comment: What did cron log say? What are printed on the standard output and standard error when executed from cron?

Comment: Note you are resetting the PATH when you say `PATH=/usr/bin`. As @Cyrus said, use full paths because cron user has a very limited environment. Also, check [debugging crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)

Comment: @fedorqui hey! Thank you for the advice. Please check the EDIT.

Comment: You should firstly make sure that the script is being executed by cron. To do this, add something like `date >> /tmp/dummy_file` and see if such info gets created. I have the impression that adding the path so that you have `* * * * * /bin/sh /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript` would fix it.

Comment: I already wrote that script is being executed if I change its source while name remains the same.

Comment: I do not know the answer to your issue at hand, and yes i'm too baffled by it (i tried to find typos or inconsistencies in your script but i couldn't).  But maybe you could instead of using cron use [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)?

Comment: @gromchmal Thanks for trying... I thing cron is a bit buggy and I will try systemd timers instead. Thank you. As long as there is alternative I will be happy.